# How to remove a leading character from numeric string? SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a list of tournament results from PGA tour data and would like to remove the "T" from the beginning of the finish column strings where applicable, so that I can get an average number. The string lengths are variable and also contain "CUT" in some rows. Is there a way to remove the "T"?

I have used...

```
WHERE Finish not like "CUT"
```

to remove "CUT" values

and have used various functions with no success to remove the "T". Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

[Showing variable string lengths in Finish column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxTWr.png)

EDIT:

This is what I have so far, which works perfectly to aggregate averages and group by player in a single row as desired.

```
SELECT

DISTINCT(player),
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(sg_putt as numeric)),2) as avg_sg_putt, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(sg_arg as numeric)),2) as avg_sg_arg, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(sg_app as numeric)),2) as avg_sg_app, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(sg_ott as numeric)),2) as avg_sg_ott, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(sg_t2g as numeric)),2) as avg_sg_t2g, 
  ROUND(AVG(CAST(sg_total as numeric)),2) as avg_sg_total,
  SUM(made_cut) as cuts_made,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(tournament_id)) as total_played,

FROM

`pga_stats_2015_2022.stats`

WHERE 

season >= 2017 AND
sg_putt not like "NA" AND
sg_arg not like "NA" AND
sg_app not like "NA" AND
sg_ott not like "NA" AND
sg_t2g not like "NA" AND
sg_total not like "NA"


GROUP BY player
HAVING total_played > 50
ORDER BY(avg_sg_total) DESC
```

Comment: Something like: SELECT REPLACE('SQL Tutorial', 'T', 'M');
may work (here im replacing t by m). I don't know if you are trying to update the data or select. But that example may help you. Here's the same to play  with it https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_replace

Comment: Maybe I need to update the column values?? I tried REPLACE but keep getting the "neither grouper nor aggregated" error message in regards to finish column. Perhaps because I'm already grouping by player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace), it seems you want `REPLACE`:

```
REPLACE(original_value, from_value, to_value)
```

So for instance,

```
SELECT REPLACE(Finish,'T','') as Finish
FROM yourTable
WHERE Finish <> 'CUT'
```

EDIT:

Looking at your full query, I suspect you want to add:

```
ROUND(AVG(CAST(REPLACE(Finish,'T','') as numeric)),2) as avg_Finish
```

to your `SELECT`.

Then add:

```
WHERE Finish <> "CUT"
```

to your `WHERE`

Comment: I tried using REPLACE as noted and got... "SELECT list expression references column Finish which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [13:11]"

Comment: EDIT: Then added a GROUP BY statement and got... "Invalid NUMERIC value: T72" ... so seems the T's are still there.

Comment: @WesleyEdward Could you share your full query? Edit your question and add it in

Comment: Thank you Aaron! I've added the full (functional) query above in the original post.

Comment: @WesleyEdward Take a look at my edit, see if that is what you are after

Comment: YESSS! I was trying to do the AVG(CAST() and REPLACE() statements separately and seems that this nested setup is exactly what the doctor ordered. Thanks!!!

Comment: @WesleyEdward Good deal, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ltrim` does the trick

```
select ltrim(finish,'T') --might want to cast to int before calculating avg
from..
where..
```

Note that `ltrim` removes all occurrences from the left so it'll remove `T` from both `T6` and `TT6` for example